# How to edit a Inline Keyboard Message Multiple times?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there any way to edit an inline keyboard message multiple times?

I tried to run the following code in a loop statement:

```
if(update.hasCallbackQuery()){
String call_data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
long message_id = update0.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();
long chat_id = update0.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId(); 
String inline_message_id = update0.getCallbackQuery().getInlineMessageId(); 
if (call_data.equals(i+"up")) {
 EditMessageReplyMarkup new_message = new EditMessageReplyMarkup() .setChatId(chat_id).setMessageId(toIntExact(message_id)) .setInlineMessageId(inline_message_id);
 InlineKeyboardButton dk1=new InlineKeyboardButton();
 dk1.setText(i+"up"); ; dk1.setCallbackData(k+"up");
 InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
 List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowsInline = new ArrayList<>();
  List<InlineKeyboardButton> rowInline = new ArrayList<>();
 rowInline.add(dk1);
  rowsInline.add(rowInline);
  markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
  new_message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
    try {editMessageReplyMarkup(new_message); } catch (TelegramApiException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

But the code run only once and i got this error:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error editing message reply markup: [400] Bad Request: message is not modified
at org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.updatingmessages.EditMessageReplyMarkup.deserializeResponse(EditMessageReplyMarkup.java:111)
 at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:690)
  at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.AbsSender.editMessageReplyMarkup(AbsSender.java:206)
   at javatelbot4.Myinkey.editinline1(Myinkey.java:83)
    at javatelbot4.Inline1.onUpdateReceived(Inline1.java:30)
      at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255)
       at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
        at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:311)
```